# Is there any way to use DatePicker in military time instead of 12hr AM/PM format?

Tags: swiftui

This may just be a limitation of DatePicker in SwiftUI, but I really want to pick my times as input in 24 hour (military) time format.  Notice in my app that wheelpicker only gives me the 12-hour format.

I was told you had to change your device settings to 24 hour format for this to work that way, but I did this and this did not change any wheelpicker options.

Anyone else have an idea on how to do this?

Here's my code with start and end times wheelpicker format.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var startTime = Date().zeroSeconds
    @State private var endTime = Date().zeroSeconds
 
    private var formatter:DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let df = DateComponentsFormatter()
        df.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
        return df
    }()

    var amountDue: Double {
        let numberIntervals = duration15 / 900
        if numberIntervals < 4 {
            return 460
        } else {
            var overTime = numberIntervals - 24
            if overTime < 0 {
                overTime = 0
            }
            return 460 + (numberIntervals-4) * 55 + (overTime * 20)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter Case Times:")) {
                    DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime , displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    DatePicker("End Time", selection: $endTime, in: startTime..., displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Times Selected:")) {
                    Text("Start Time = \(startTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                    Text("End Time = \(endTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Case Duration:")) {
                    Text("duration = \(self.durationStr)")
                    Text("duration (rounded) = \(self.duration15Str)")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Amount Due:")) {
                    Text(amountDue, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("DDA Rates Calculator")
        }
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval {
        guard endTime > startTime else {
            return 0
        }
        return (DateInterval(start: startTime, end: endTime).duration)
    }
    
    var duration15: TimeInterval {
        return  ((self.duration/900.0).rounded(.up)*900)
    }
    
    var durationStr: String {
        let duration = self.duration
        guard duration > 1 else {
            return "----"
        }
        return formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "----"
    }
    
     var duration15Str: String {
        let duration = duration15
        guard duration > 1 else {
            return "----"
        }
        return formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "----"
     }
        
}

extension Date {
    var zeroSeconds: Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self)
        return calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? self
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any resources on the web or in Apple Developer documentation that supports what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you happen to test the device settings change on a real device or just the simulator? It not then it 'might' just be a simulator issue.

Comment: Yes, I just now realized this and when I changed the setting on the REAL device to 24 hour time, it actually worked!  But, to be honest, I don't find that to be an adequate solution to my problem.  I only have one app that needs military time (for billing purposes), but why would I have to change the ENTIRE phone settings in order to use DatePicker they way I want?

Comment: You could build your own picker where combine two Picker objects to select hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by changing my device (iPhone) that I downloaded code to.  Doesn't work in simulator mode.

Not ideal as I didn't want to change my iPhone to military for just one app.  Guess I'd have to either write my own Datepicker or see if Apple updates theirs to have a modifier for this.